# Can i use grep to search words on the content that i already have in terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep

I am new here and in the Linux world. So i am wondering if it is possible to search for a word in the content that i already have in my terminal. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly --

You have to copy the whole terminal content and save them into a file, before you can use `grep` to search words on the content.

Copying the content from terminal various from terminal to terminal, but I bet yours has a menu which allows you doing so.

If you can plan ahead, check out `script` - make typescript of terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can use the `script` command to record all your terminal output to a file called `typescript` and then search that file later.

Out-of-the-box however, you can use `grep` on all the commands you've entered. For example:

```
$ grep eyesome ~/.bash_history
cd eyesome
gedit eyesome-src.sh
sudo eyesome/movie.sh
pgrep eyesome
sudo eyesome/movie.sh a
cat /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunrise
cat /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunset
sudo eyesome/movie.sh
sudo ~/eyesome/movie.sh
~/eyesome/movie.sh
~/eyesome/movie.sh
cd ../eyesome
ll ../.eyesome*
ll ../.eyesome-cfg
rm /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-cfg.bad*
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-cfg.bad*
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-cfg.fast
sgedit eyesome-cfg.sh
```

Simply use your search string (in this case `eyesome`) and specify the command history file name which is `~/.bash_history`.